# Installing SQL Server using config.ini

Tags: sql-server, powershell, windows-server

I'm trying to install SQL using a config.ini file but it doesn't seem to accept the parameters set in the file.

For example, at the top of my file I have:

```
;SQL Server 2017 Configuration File
[OPTIONS]

IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS="True"
```

I run this:

`C:\Temp\sql-server-2017.exe /ConfigurationFile="C:\Temp\sql-config.ini"`

And yet, it will open the install window and ask me to "Accept Terms"

Another example, I have quiet simple set to true:

```
; Setup will not display any user interface. 

QUIET="False"

; Setup will display progress only, without any user interaction. 

QUIETSIMPLE="True"
```

But when I run: `C:\Temp\sql-server-2017.exe /ConfigurationFile=C:\Temp\sql-config.ini /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /MediaPath=C:\Temp\SQL`

I get this in the summary and error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: How sure are you about your config file? Your screenshot shows Quiet and QuietSimple both = true which would explain your last error. Installing SQL 2014 we use /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms and /ConfigurationFile successfully. Maybe 2017 is different?

Comment: So yea the summary shows that but the actually `ini` file is set to `quiet=false and quiestsimple=true` that's why I'm confused

Comment: What happens when you run `C:\Temp\sql-server-2017.exe /ConfigurationFile=C:\Temp\sql-config.ini /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /MediaPath=C:\Temp\SQL /Q` ? From [BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt) - `Unattended installations (using the /Q or /QS parameters) must include the /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS parameter.`